# 3 cards of 52, Making Straight or better with 2 imaginary wild Jokers

Tags: combinatorics

Random shuffled 52-card deck, 3 cards are dealt.

Find a probability of making 5-card Straight or better with imaginary 2 wild Jokers.

In order to make Straight or better, we need the three cards to represent either of the following:

1. Three of a kind,
2. A pair,
3. 3 suited cards,
4. 3 cards to a straight

Total combinations: C(52,3) = 22,100

- Three of a kind: 
  Choose 1 of 13 ranks, choose 3 out of the 4 same rank of cards: C(4,3)=4
  N= C(13,1)*C(4,3) = 52.
- A pair:
  Choose 1 of 13 ranks, choose 2 out of the 4 same rank of cards: C(4,2)=6
  For the remaining 3rd card, we can choose any of the other ranks' 48 cards.
  N= C(13,1)*C(4,2)*48 = 3744
- 3 suited cards:
  Choose 3 of the 13 from a suit: C(13,3)=286, times any of the 4 suits.
  N=286*4=1144
- 3 to a straight:
  We take the smallest card of each comb for the reference point.
  If the smallest card is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, the possible straight combinations are 6 for each card.
- n, n+1, n+2
- n, n+1, n+3
- n, n+1, n+4
- n, n+2, n+3
- n, n+2, n+4
- n, n+3, n+4

If the smallest card is J, such combinations are only 3:

- JQK
- JQA
- JKA

and in case of Q, there is only one combination:

- QKA

Total: 64 triplets.

We multiply 64 by the suits each card can take, 4*4*4=64, but need to subtract the all-same-suit variants (to exclude flushes): one for each suit (total of 4).

N= 64*(64-4) = 3840

N_Total: 52 + 3744 + 1144 + 3840 = 8780

P_Total: 8780 / 22100 = 0.3973

Since I didn't calculate the rest of the hands to make sure all probabilities add up to 100%, I would like to ask for verification of my method and calculations, please. Method being the most important part of my question.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Both the method and the numbers appear to be correct.

Comment: Do you need to calculate having three of a kind or better?  If you have 3 of a kind you have a pair and that's enough, isn't it.

Comment: I don't see any compensation for double counting (maybe I just missed) it.  If you have 3 of a kind then you have a pair.  And there is overlap on suited pair cards and potential straight.  Example 5,6 and 9 of diamonds  I both a straight and a flush.

Comment: Oh, I see where you compensated for double counting.  (I think it'd be easier to just do pairs.)

Comment: @fleablood - You are correct, it was easier to do with the pairs. I was just making sure I was not missing flops of any configuration. Besides, it was testing my abilities for enumeration.

Comment: Yeah, this was a tricky one to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian commented, the method and the numbers appear to be correct.

Note that to count the $3$ to a straight, you could have said that there are $\binom42$, $\binom32$ and $\binom22$ possibilities, respectively, since you can choose any $2$ of the up to $4$ cards above the lowest.

Comment: That's an excellent idea and more elegant approach. Thanks.